# How do you determine if a WiX installer is quiet or interactive?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Is there a way within WiX to determine if the installer is being run in quiet mode or interactively?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My google-fu finally kicked in.  Apparently there are some built-in properties that you can use to determine the UI level.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372096%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: These don't seem to work for me. I'm trying to use `INSTALLUILEVEL_FULL` as a property in a condition for a `Custom`, doesn't seem to be set when running (though I am just using `WixUI_InstallDir` so this could be an issue).

Comment: @NickBolton: Afaik, the property is `UILevel` and not `INSTALLUILEVEL_FULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Recently we developed new bundled WiX installers in our team where we had our custom bootstrapper application inheriting from standard `BootstrapperApplication` and we were checking whether the installation is silent like this:

```
(Command.Display == Display.None || Command.Display == Display.Embedded)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this now, you can do Condition.NOT_Silent or Silent in WiX. ManagedAction classes support that, for example when doing
`project.AddAction(new ManagedAction(CustomActions.RunAfterInstall, Return.check, When.After, Step.InstallFinalize, Condition.NOT_Installed));`